# Comportamento anormal ao pegar dados de um FormGroup com Angular

Tags: html5, angular, typescript, materialize

Estava terminando um formulário usando Angular e Materialize e notei que não estava recebendo os dados de campos gerados com "[datepicker](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html)" do Materialize, mesmo que possuam texto válido.

**HTML**:

```
<form [formGroup]="dataForm" (ngSubmit)="ngSubmit()">
  <div class="input-field">
    <input
      id="my_data"
      type="text"
      formControlName="my_data"
      placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
      class="datepicker"/>
    <label for="my_data">Data escolhida</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn-large blue pf-block" type="submit">Salvar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Inicialização dos componentes e emissão de formulário**:

> Inicializando o componente:

```
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, {
      format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    });

  this.operationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    my_data: ['', Validators.required],
  });
}
```

> Usando a função `ngSubmit()` para analisar os valores retornados pelo campo:

```
ngSubmit(){
    console.log("my_data");
    console.log(this.operationForm.get("my_data"));
    console.log(this.operationForm.get("my_data").value)
    console.log(document.getElementById("my_data").nodeValue)
}
```

**Seleção da data com o picker**:

[image: selecionando a data com o picker]

[image: campo com a data já selecionada]

`Resultado da emissão`:

[image: resultado dos logs no console]

É possível, inclusive, perceber que o sistema interpreta o campo como possuindo como valor uma string vazia, como é possível ver a seguir:

[image: valor armazenado dentro do objeto]

Como fazer o conteúdo do campo ser lido de forma correta (retornando a string "23/10/2019") ao invés de uma string vazia?

**Atualização**: tentei retirar as opções de inicialização do elemento, trocando `M.Datepicker.init(elems, {format: "dd/mm/yyyy"});` por `M.Datepicker.init(elems);`. O problema persistiu.

**Atualização**: estou tentando evitar o uso do `jQuery` por alguns conflitos que ele estava gerando com certos componentes ao manipular o DOM. Então se tiver como fazer utilizando javascript puro ou typescript, ficaria mais interessante. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remova o form control do input, pois iremos obter o valor de forma explicita

```
<form [formGroup]="dataForm" (ngSubmit)="ngSubmit()">
  <div class="input-field">
    <input
      id="my_data"
      type="text"
      placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
      class="datepicker"/>
    <label for="my_data">Data escolhida</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="btn-large blue pf-block" type="submit">Salvar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Neste exemplo, obtemos a data selecionada e atualizamos o `value` do form control com a mesma.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, {
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        this.operationForm.controls['my_data'].setValue(dateText);
    },
});
```

Comment: Tem como fazer isso sem utilizar jQuery?

Comment: Sim, vou editar

Comment: e se eu tiver dois campos, com ids diferentes (como `enter_at` e `exit_at`)?

Comment: @ArthurSiqueira detalhe melhor em outra pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Salve @Arthur Siqueira.

Tenta assim a chamada do Datepicker:

```
<script>
$('#my_data').datepicker({ 
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Mar&ccedil;o', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda-feira', 'Ter&ccedil;a-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'S&aacute;bado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'S&aacute;b'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'S&aacute;b']
    });
</script>
```

Além de personalizar o nome dos meses e dias da semana para o Português, vc tem um controle maior das regras que podem ser usadas no Datepicker.

Obs: "minDate: 0" serve para setar apenas valores futuros na data, caso não seja o seu caso é só retirar.

O teu input ficaria assim:

```
<input type="text" name="my_data" id="my_data" autocomplete="off" class="inputData_false" placeholder="Clique e escolha um dia">
```

Abaixo um pequeno script para previnir a inserção de qualquer conteúdo que não seja o esperado no input do datepicker:

```
<script>
    $(".inputData_false").on("keydown", function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

Lembre-se de importar no seu projeto sempre a versão do jQuery UI mais recente para evitar bugs (atualmente está na versão 1.12.4).

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Espero que eu tenha ajudado.